# How to deserialize JSON from Web API to class

Tags: c#, json, dotnet-httpclient

so I'm a beginner for JSON and I'm having a hard time to put it in a class from a web API. I used postman to get this so far:

```
 {
    "$id": "1",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Quick Entry",
    "description": "General",
    "trackerNumber": 1,
    "taskType": 0,
    "priority": 1,
    "status": 0,
    "isRecurring": 1,
    "clientVisibility": null,
    "dateCreated": "2015-05-04T11:45:58.867",
    "dateModified": "2017-03-29T11:51:52.007",
    "modifiedBySessionId": "f1a96bf3-7e08-4d44-b8a2-5eacf0adab01",
    "hours": null,
    "deliveryDate": null,
    "discriminator": "",
    "assignedToUserId": null,
    "projectId": 1,
    "clientId": 1,
    "sortOrder": 4,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "folder": "33f16cea-7fb4-e511-80db-00155d001801",
    "taskGroupId": 1,
    "isNew": false
}
```

"task" is the name of the class that I made. And this is my code behind:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:45552/") })
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);
    var test = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("api/Tasks/1");

    //task = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TaskInfo>(test);

    Console.WriteLine(task.Name);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I'm just not sure how to deserialize it.

My JSON class:

```
class TaskInfo
{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "trackerNumber")]
    public int TrackerNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "taskType")]
    public int TaskType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "priority")]
    public int Priority { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "isRecurring")]
    public int IsRecurring { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "clientVisibility")]
    public int ClientVisibility { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dateCreated")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dateModified")]
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "modifiedBySessionId")]
    public string ModifiedBySessionId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hours")]
    public int Hours { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "deliveryDate")]
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "discriminator")]
    public string Discriminator { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "assignedToUserId")]
    public int AssignedToUserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "projectId")]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "clientId")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sortOrder")]
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "isDeleted")]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "folder")]
    public int Folder { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "taskGroupId")]
    public int TaskGroupId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "isNew")]
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }

}
```

And when I try to print my task class, it gives me this error:
"Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path 'clientVisibility', line 1, position 157."

Comment: Do you have a class that represents your JSON?

Comment: yes <TaskInfo>.

Comment: Ok so uncomment this line `task = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TaskInfo>(test);` Thats exactly how you deserialize strings to a known type

Comment: I tried doing that and tried printing something from that class and it didn't work. I'll add my class for my JSON

Comment: "It didnt work" -- Why didnt it work?  We need **specifics** to try and diagnose the problem you are having

Comment: when I try printing my class task.names, it gives me this error = "Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path 'clientVisibility', line 1, position 157."

Comment: For possible `null` values use `Nullable<int>` as type for the property

Comment: @PankajKapare but I declared it already in my json class right? sorry im so loss here

Comment: @Marq: Change type of ClientVisibility property from int to int? in TaskInfo class as suggested by Fabio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is this, you have declared `ClientVisibility` in you C# class as an `int` and not a nullable `int`.  It should be like this:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "clientVisibility")]
public int? ClientVisibility { get; set; }
```

In your JSON you passing the property as null:

```
"clientVisibility": null
```

Therefore the C# class property must be able to accept null values as I've shown above.  The same will also apply to any other `int` properties that have to accept `null` such as `Hours`